# Unexpected relative value of eigenvalues of $A^\top A$ and $(A^\top A)^{-1}$ in a highly co-linear OLS model

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I'm afraid the answer is embarrassingly obvious, but here it goes... I was playing with R trying to get "giant" ([Prof. Strang's word](https://youtu.be/Z_5uLqcwDgM?t=866) when explaining penalized regression) inverses of $A^\top A$ (/a-transpose-a/, Gram model matrices) in the presence of highly co-linear regressors. I remember the relationship of the inverse of $A^\top A$ to the variance of the parameter estimates - a direct relationship $\text{Var} (\hat \beta) = \sigma^2 \left(A^\top A \right)^{-1},$ indicating that the high variance of the estimates in the presence of collinearity is related to high values in the *inverse* of the $A^\top A$ matrix. Of course this is [addressed on the site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134008/67822):

> If two or more columns of $A$ are highly correlated, one or more eigenvalue(s) of $A^\top A$ is close to zero and one or more eigenvalue(s) of $(A^\top A)^{−1}$ is very large.

Yet, to my surprise, it was $A^\top A,$ and not $(A^\top A)^{-1},$ the matrix with huge eigenvalues.

The toy model is trying to predict the yearly income based on paid income taxes and weekend expenses, and all variables are highly correlated:

$$\text{income} \sim \text{income taxes} + \text{money spent on weekends}$$

```
# The manufacturing of the toy dataset with 100 entries
weekend_expend = runif(100, 100, 2000)
income = weekend_expend * 100 + runif(100, 10000, 20000)
taxes = 0.4 * income + runif(100, 10000, 20000)
df = cbind(income, taxes, weekend_expend)
pairs(df)
```

[image]

```
> summary(mod <- lm(income ~ weekend_expend + taxes))

Call:
lm(formula = income ~ weekend_expend + taxes)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5337.7 -1885.9   165.8  2028.1  5474.6 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    5260.14790 1656.95983   3.175              0.00201 ** 
weekend_expend   81.55490    3.07497  26.522 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
taxes             0.46616    0.07543   6.180         0.0000000151 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2505 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9981,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9981 
F-statistic: 2.551e+04 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 0.00000000000000022

> # The model matrix is of the form...
> head(A <- model.matrix(mod))
  (Intercept) weekend_expend    taxes
1           1      1803.8237 92743.93
2           1       441.6305 33697.32
3           1       379.0888 36401.24
4           1      1129.1074 65869.23
5           1       558.3715 36708.88
6           1      1790.5604 92750.60
>
> And the A transpose A is...
> (A_tr_A <- t(A) %*% A)
               (Intercept) weekend_expend        taxes
(Intercept)          100.0       113189.2      6632490
weekend_expend    113189.2    159871091.4   8788158840
taxes            6632489.5   8788158839.9 492672410430
>
> ... with its inverse...
> (inv_A_tr_A <- solve(A_tr_A))
                  (Intercept)    weekend_expend               taxes
(Intercept)     0.43758617285  0.00072025324389 -0.0000187385886210
weekend_expend  0.00072025324  0.00000150703080 -0.0000000365782573
taxes          -0.00001873859 -0.00000003657826  0.0000000009067669
> 
> The eigenvalues of the A transpose A are...
> eigen(A_tr_A)$values
[1] 492829172338.305359      3109280.897155            2.285258
>
> "Huge" as compared to the eigenvalues of its transposed...
> eigen(inv_A_tr_A)$values
[1] 0.437587359169068602 0.000000321617773712 0.000000000002029101
```

The maximum eigenvalue of $A^\top A$ is $492829172338$ while for $(A^\top A)^{-1}$ we get eigenvalues as low as $0.000000000002029101.$

> I was expecting the opposite to be the case: Much higher eigenvalues for the inverse of $A^\top A.$ So is this result spurious, or am I missing something critical?

Comment: OK, cool. Saw the clip. I am pretty sure that Prof. Strong refers to the condition number when he says *$A^T A$ has a giant inverse*" as he immediately qualifies this by saying "*the matrix $A$ is badly conditioned.*"  in both cases of the examples you created, the condition number (ratio of largest to smallest eigenvalue) is `~2e11` which is rather large. Also note that if you perform`A <- 1/A` i.e. the magnitude of the values in the original matrix $A$ was reverse we would get "large numbers"  for the inverse of $A^TA$.

Comment: Matrix $A$ is badly conditioned because of the condition number not the sheer magnitude of the numbers (usually at least, unless the columns are at vastly different scales too but that's another game).

Comment: @usεr11852 Can you dumb it down a bit? I see the overall problem, but it seems key that it is the inverse of a transpose a the matrix with high eigenvalues so that the variance of the estimates turns out high...

Comment: @usεr11852 ... although now it makes already a lot of sense... The "condition number"!!! Thank you very much, BTW!

Comment: The man is an artist. You got to go with the flow. (+1 obviously to the question cause it's fun)

Comment: The inverse of a matrix with eigenvalues $[3, 2, 1]$ has eigenvalues $[1/1, 1/2, 1/3]$. The condition number is still the same, $3$. Now I think the crux is that you say: "*high variance of the estimates in the presence of colinearity (typo) is related to high values in the inverse of the $A^TA$ matrix*", the values are not is not the root issue of the high variance. It is that the condition number as it suggest that a small change in the inputs (the explanatory variables) there will be a large change in the answer or dependent variable.

Comment: @usεr11852 How can I explain to myself the quote above: If two or more columns of $A$ are highly correlated, one or more eigenvalue(s) of $A^\top A$ is close to zero and one or more eigenvalue(s) of $(A^\top A)^{−1}$ is very large.

Comment: $A^TA$ will be have an eigenvalue close to zero (i.e. an (orthogonal_ dimension with very little magnitude of variation) because the original matrix $A$ will have a very uninformative column; the column $x_1$ that it will be correlated with column $x_2$. In that way when we will take the inner product of $A$ we will end up with a degenerate kernel (matrix in this case) $A^TA$. Also to see a 0-th eigenvalue try `eigen(cov(A))` which will effectively scale the columns of $A$ first.

Comment: @usεr11852 But $A^TA$ doesn't have an eigenvalue close to zero: $492829172338,     3109280, 2$ are the eigenvalues. What am I missing?

Comment: Edited my answer on that. :) You can also try `svd(scale(A,scale = FALSE))$d` and see that just centring the values will do the trick.

Comment: @usεr11852 Is $2$ considered the eigenvalue close to zero?

Comment: @usεr11852 So basically we see this effect only when the mean of each column is centered at zero? Even so, the e-values of the inverse should be larger than the original...

Comment: Yes. Also note that eigenvalues are "relative to each other". So, yes, if the one is `492829172338` and the other is `2`, `2` is "close to zero" as realistically if we normalised the "large one" to be at scale $1$ the other one will be at scale 10^{-12}.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you very much. What about the inverse having to have larger e-values than a transpose a? I guess we are trying to invert a matrix with a virtually zero e-value (after centering)... Makes sense...

Comment: @usεr11852 It would be terrific to have all these concepts in a formal answer :-)

Comment: Pleasure Antoni! It is a bit late here and I need to something else but I can sort this out tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particular to the video segment linked Prof. Strong refers to the matrix [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) when he says "*$A^TA$ has a giant inverse*" as he immediately qualifies this by saying "*the matrix $A$ is badly conditioned*". Please note that condition number relates to the magnitude of the eigenvalues in the original matrix $A^TA$. That means that the concept of a "small/large eigenvalue" is purely relative. In the example provided, if the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is `492829172338` and the  smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_3$ is `2`, `2` is "close to zero" because if we normalised $\lambda_1$ to be unit scale, $\lambda_3$ will be at scale $10^{-12}$.

Now regarding the inverse $(A^TA)^{-1}$: The condition number of a matrix $B$ and the inverse of it $B^{-1}$ (given $B^{-1}$ exists of course) is the same.
For example if the $B$ has  eigenvalues $[3,2,1]$, $B^{-1}$ will have eigenvalues $[1/1,1/2,1/3]$. The condition number is still the same. Cleve Moller's blog-post on [*What is the Condition Number of a Matrix?*](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/07/17/what-is-the-condition-number-of-a-matrix/) is an excellent conversational take on this. Notice that this relates directly to what is mention as: "*high variance of the estimates in the presence of collinearity is related to high values in the inverse of the $A^TA$ matrix*"; the high values are not  the root issue of the high variance in themselves. It is that the condition number as it suggest that for a small change in the inputs (the explanatory variables) we will have a large change in our response variable.

Finally, as in regards to the side question: "*(Why) if two or more columns of $A$ are highly correlated, one or more eigenvalue(s) of $A^TA$ is close to zero (...)?*" As mentioned, this relates to the original matrix  having a very uninformative column (as one of them will just a rescaled version of another column) and therefore the columns of $A$ are *not* linearly independent. This column-space deficiency causes $A^TA$ to be what we call degenerate (or singular) matrix. I started writing more on this but I saw that ttnphns has given an absolute unit of an answer in the thread: *[What correlation makes a matrix singular and what are implications of singularity or near-singularity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70899/what-correlation-makes-a-matrix-singular-and-what-are-implications-of-singularit/70910#70910)*.

Comment: Thank you! I'll come back to accept.

Comment: Cool! I am glad I could help!