# How to Prove that Multicollinearity is "Bad"?

Tags: regression

Multicollinearity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) is when two or more predictor variables are heavily correlated with each other.

As an example, if you have "weight" and "height" as predictor variables in a regression model - if you were to include the "ratio of weight and height" as a new predictor variable, you might now have multicollinearity in your model.

When multicollinearity is present, it is said that this can result in problems. For example:

- If there is a high degree of multicollinearity, the OLS matrix can become non-invertible which leads to not being able to estimate the regression coefficients (I am not sure as to why multicollinearity makes the matrix non-invertible). I think this is what is referred to as "non-identifiability"
- If there is a high degree of multicollinearity, the estimates of the regression coefficients are said to become "unstable" and significantly change when re-estimated using new data (but again, I am not sure why this happens)

**My Question:** Can someone please suggest how we can use demonstrate (e.g. using linear algebra) that multicollinearity results in these two adverse phenomena?

Thanks!

- Note: Apparently techniques such as (LASSO) Regularization and models such as Random Forest are believed to be less affected by multicollinearity. I can understand that in the case of Random Forest, sets of predictor variables with high multicollinearity might be "ignored over time" - but I am not sure why Regularization (e.g. pushing some of the regression coefficients to 0) can reduce multicollinearity (e.g. how do we know that Regularization will specifically concentrate on the multicollinear predictors?)
- References: [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat401/lecture-17.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=stat401/lecture-17.pdf)
- [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/lecture-17.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/lecture-17.pdf)

Comment: multicollinearity is only bad if we want to know what the regression coefficients are. If we're only interested in prediction, it has no bearing. The reason it messes with estimates of the regression coefficients is that multiple distinct coefficients lead to identical predictions. [From a linear algebraic perspective: If the design matrix is rank deficient, its right nullspace is nontrivial, and hence vectors in that nullspace correspond to directions along which perturbing a given coefficient vector will result in no change to model predictions.]

Comment: Answering the first request begins and ends with the **invertible matrix theorem.** Any introductory linear algebra textbook will cover the relationship between colinearity, invertibility, and regression.

Comment: Some of the trouble with discussing multicollinearity is that people seem to assume their remedies not to introduce their own issues. For instance, dropping a variable that is correlated with another can relieve multicollinearity, sure, but doing so risks biasing the included parameters. It is not obvious that you will be better off with a more precise (maybe, parameter variance also depends on residual variance, which can increase if you drop parameters) biased estimate than a less accurate unbiased estimate. Then, if bias is acceptable, why not explore other biased estimators?

Comment: @ sycorax: Thank you for your reply! regarding the first question, all I could find was this  : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134007/invertibility-of-xtx-with-severe-multicollinearity-in-regression . I can understand that certain types of matrices are non-invertible, but I am not sure as to why multicollinearity would lead to the OLS matrix being non-invertible?

Comment: @ john madden: thank you for your reply! is there a mathematical reference for this? how do I understand "multiple distinct coefficients lead to identical predictions."?

Comment: @ Dave: Thank you for your reply! I am dealing with the following question and thought of the following approach: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603514/can-any-model-be-modified-into-an-autoregressive-model . I was not sure if the approach I described would result in multicollinearity . I am trying to learn more about multicollinearity to see if this is the case. If you have time, could you please take a look at my question and let me know your thoughts? Thank you so much!

Comment: Consult a textbook. If you need a recommendation, there are dozens of threads providing helpful references.